# limsup of continuous function is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to show that if $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then

$$\limsup_{h \rightarrow0, h>0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$

is measurable.

By the definition of $\limsup$ we can write
\begin{align}
&\limsup_{h \rightarrow0, h>0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\left(\sup_{0<h<\delta} \ \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\sup_{0<h<\frac{1}{n}} \ \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}\right).
\end{align}
If we show $\sup_{0<h<\frac{1}{n}} \ \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$ is measurable then we can use the fact that limit of a countable sequence of measurable functions is also measurable.

I want to show that $$\sup_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\sup_{0<h<\delta,h \in \mathbb{Q}}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$ It suffices to show that $$\sup_{0<h<\delta,h \in \mathbb{Q}}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}\geq \sup_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$. Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $0<h_0<\delta$ such that $$\frac{F(x+h_0)-F(x)}{h_0}>\sup_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}-\epsilon$$ Let's fix $x$. Since $\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$ is a continuous function with variable $h$, there exists a rational $0<q<\delta$ close enough to $h_0$ such that $$\left|\frac{F(x+q)-F(x)}{q}-\frac{F(x+h_0)-F(x)}{h_0}\right|<\epsilon$$ Therefore, $$\frac{F(x+q)-F(x)}{q}>\sup_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}-2\epsilon$$ Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $$\sup_{0<h<\delta,h \in \mathbb{Q}}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}\geq \sup_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$

Comment: You have not used continuity so far. Try to figure out how to make the supremum over a countable set. Maybe just rational $h$ in $0<h<\delta$ are enough?

Comment: I updated it. I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Yes, it looks good.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way of proving that $$\sup_{0<h<\delta,h\in \mathbb Q} \frac {F(x+h)-F(x)} h =\sup_{0<h<\delta} \frac {F(x+h)-F(x)} h$$ is to note that if $$\frac {F(x+h)-F(x)} {h} \leq M$$ for $$0<h<\delta,h\in \mathbb Q$$ then $$\frac {F(x+h)-F(x)} {h} \leq M$$ for $$0<h<\delta .$$ Hence the two suprema are the same . [Take $M$ to be the RHS and note that each side of the equation is less than or equal to the other]

Comment: I didn't understand where you used the continuity assumption.

Comment: @S_Alex Given $0<h<\delta$ choose $\{h_n\} \subset (0,\delta)\cap \mathbb Q$ such that $h_n \to h$. Then $\frac {F(x+h_n)-F(x)} {h_n} \leq M$ for each $n$. Let $n \to \infty$ to get $\frac {F(x+h)-F(x)} {h} \leq M$.